# Attach bootstrap tooltip to elements by class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I'm trying to attach a bootstrap tooltip to all elements on a page by class but can't get it to work.

When my page displays, if there are any validation errors (validation is done server side), the error messages are inside DIVs with `class=error` as below

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input class="form-control" id="reference" name="reference" placeholder="Reference" required="">
  </div>
  <div id="reference_error" class="error">Field has error</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    <input class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" required="">
  </div>
  <div id="surname_error" class="error">Field has error</div>
</div>
```

The DIVs are hidden with the css below because the idea is to show the error in a tooltip insted

```
.error {
    display:none
}
```

Finally, I have the following jQuery function to iterate through all of the error messages and show them as toottips

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".error").each(function(index) {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.parent(".form-group").popover({
       trigger: 'manual',
       placement: 'right',
       content: function () {
           return $el.text();
       }
   }).popover('show');
  });
});
```

When this runs, the tooltips do appear, but not attached to the elements I want....they're floating up the page.

Does anyone know how I can get this working or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Seems that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/7befmLbn/

Comment: @Artur I don't know what was happening earlier, but you're right - it seems to be working now. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: I've just managed to re-create this.....it happens for me when I re-size the window to anything less than full screen. Artur's jsfiddle still seems to work with a re-sized window though. The only difference I can see is the jsfiddle form-control class has a width, so I'll test that later. At least I know I'm not going mad now! :)